# Setting route value of main url from a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, partial-views

I'm working on a multi-language ASP.NET MVC site, and I need some help setting the language in the main action from a partial view.

My default route is declared as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { language = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In my _Layout.cshtml, I've declared a partial reference as:

```
@Html.Partial("_LanguagePartial")
```

This Partial invokes an Action in the Language Controller:

```
@Html.Action("Index","Language")
```

This controller action just pumps the released languages to the view:

```
public class LanguageController : BaseController
{
    //
    // GET: /Language/
    public PartialViewResult Index()
    {
        List<Language> languages = new List<Language>();
        foreach (Language language in Global.Data.Languages.Values)
        {
            if (language.IsReleased)
                languages.Add(language);
        }
        return PartialView(languages);
    }

    public ActionResult SelectLanguage(string code)
    {
        //I tried to change the route value here, but this only affects the route to this action
        var routeDataDict = HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values;
        routeDataDict["language"] = code;
        return RedirectToRoute(routeDataDict);
    }
}
```

The actual view that is shown in the partial, looks like this:

```
<div class="float-center">
<table><tr>
@foreach (var language in Model) {
    <td>
    <a href="@Url.Action("SelectLanguage", new { code = language.CultureCode })">
        <!--The css for the correct sprite is generated by language.Icon.ToString()
            The result will look like "background: url("/Images/Icons.png") -0px -100px; display: block; width: 32px; height: 20px; text-indent: -9999px;"-->
        <img alt="" src="" style="@Url.Content(@language.Icon.ToString());border=1" />
    </a>
    </td>
}
</tr></table>
```

Now this partial is rendered in every page of the site, like it should, but when I'm for example on mydomain/en/SomeController/SomeAction and I click on let's say the German icon, it should take me to mydomain/de/SomeController/SomeAction.

Off course the action and controller are not fixed.

Any ideas on how I can perform such an action?
Maybe I've implemented the partial wrong and I'll be able to access the route if I implement it differently.

**EDIT:**
With the help of meilke's answer, I've made following edit to the Language controller:

```
public ActionResult SelectLanguage(string code)
    {
        string url = ReplaceLanguageCode(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), code);
        return Redirect(url);
    }

    private string ReplaceLanguageCode(string url, string code)
    {
        Language language = GetLanguage(url);
        if (language == null)
        {
            //No Language is set in the url e.g. http://mydomain/
            string domain = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, "");
            return url.Replace(domain, domain + "/" + code);
        }
        else
            //A Language was already set in the url e.g. http://mydomain/en/
            return url.Replace("/" + language.CultureCode + "/", "/" + code + "/");
    }

    private Language GetLanguage(string url)
    {
        //Loop the apps languages to see if one is set in the url
        foreach (Language language in Global.Data.Languages.Values)
        {
            if (url.ToLower().Contains("/" + language.CultureCode + "/"))
                return language;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The SetLanguage action is changed to use the UrlReferrer as stated by meilke's answer. I also added ReplaceLanguageCode to create the new url and GetLanguage to get the language if the original url contains one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a general controller which is regardless of the current action or current controller and place the `SelectLanguage` in there. Then make use of `Request.UrlReferrer` ([more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc680820%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to get you back to where you came from (now using the correct language):

```
public ActionResult SelectLanguage(string code)
{
  // set language here

  return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with a General controller? A custom controller where all my other controllers derive from?

Comment: I was thinking about some central controller but you could still use `LanguageController`. The idea is to have a hook where you can set the new language (cookies?) and redirect back (without having to specify what exactly back is because `Request.UrlReferrer` knows).

Comment: Thanks, with the UrlReferrer I can actually get the main url and I can just replace the language code and do a redirect. I'll edit my original question to show how it is done now for future reference